# Reading data from serial port

Tags: linux, serial-port, busybox, read, stty

FYI I am running busybox. I am able to send data to my ttyS1 using the following command:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyS1 speed 115200 cs8 -cstopb -parenb -echo
echo -en 'data here' > /dev/ttyS1
```

But when I try to read, I do this:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyS1 speed 115200 cs8 -cstopb -parenb -echo
cat /dev/ttyS1
```

But program ends without any messages.
I also tried `cat < /dev/ttyS1` doesn't work either.

I am positive that the data is being sent to this port since I have LED indicator to indicate data is coming. And Connection Settings are set to be same as 115200 baud, 8bit, Even Parity, 1stopbit.

Comment: Have you tried using `minicom` or an equivalent?

Comment: As I am using busybox std, I cannot install any new app on this OS due to space constraint on my device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So found answer in another forum. I will put it here, basically just add timeout timing and a while loop to constantly read the port.

```
stty -F /dev/ttyS1 speed 115200 cs8 -cstopb -parenb -echo time 3 min 0
while [ true ]; do
   cat /dev/ttyS1
done
```

That's all.